# manage shared hosting with linux commands

Tags: linux, hosting, shared-hosting

I have a dedicate Linux server on a data center and now i installed LAMP on it, it works perfectly, But i have a question. I have to config this server to sell shared hots to customers, then i need to install Cpanel or Direct admin or one of others... but because of i want to learn system core, i don't want to install this things, I want to manage whole system by Linux commands... how i can do this? i mean what is the starting point? i know Linux and its concepts and work with it everyday. i need some references  to my goal. please help me to do this. i want to learn new things and sell my hosts beside it... thanks

Comment: You are asking for 10+ years of career sysadmin knowledge to be magically dropped into your brain - Server Fault can't do that. A production system which is providing services to customers who are paying you money is ***NOT*** the environment for you to be "learning" on - If you're not comfortable managing the system on your own you need to bring someone in to do that job for you. You can work alongside them and learn, but please don't use your paying customers as lab rats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, you should know your systems abilities before you configure the server as a shared hosting server. The key components are, Network(UP/DOWN), CPU, Memory and disk space. As a side note, do not use LAMP server. Instead use a package manager provided by your Operating System and install these services one by one.

Secondly, if you are configuring the server to host multiple websites from the same IP address you should be reading about **vhosts** (Virtual Hosts).

Hope this puts you in the right track.

Comment: thanks @val0x00ff. vhosts is my solution.but for examle for managing dns, email and... ?

Comment: @FarhadShirzad, Managing dns and email can be done using either CLI or a management web interface like webmin. You can configure Bind(for DNS) and Postfix or Exim as a MTA(Mail Transfer Agent). Both work perfect. To prevent spam you can configure Spamasassin with postfix/. Manually configuring these service will require a lot of time and energy.